# Cannot set Foreground Color to a TreeView DataTemplate TextBlock (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview, bind, datatemplate

I bind a TreeNode item list to a tree view. I am not able to bind to the DataTemplate TextBlock the Foreground color.

Initally I tought it is a binding problem, so I tried to give it a color manually, namely `Foreground="Red"` but I figured even like this it does not change my text color.

xaml:

```
 <TreeView  ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewNodesPLCCode}" >
         <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <Grid>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{Binding Path=MachineObject.Color}"/>
                     </Grid>
               </DataTemplate>
          </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
   </TreeView>
```

Code:

```
TreeViewNodesPLCCode=new ObservableCollection<TreeNode>()

 public class TreeNode: TreeViewItem
    {
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public Machine MachineObject { get; set; }
    }
  public class Machine
    {
        public Int32 ID { get; set; }
        public Brush Color { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try your code, I get the following output in Visual Studio:

> ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of
>   the ItemsControl's container type; Type='TreeNode'

This means that you are adding in the `TreeView` items that can be added directly without an `DataTemplate`.

`DataTemplate` are made to visualize data objects (i.e. your business objects). `TreeViewItem` already have a `DataTemplate`.

To solve your issue, remove the inheritance to `TreeViewItem` for your class `TreeNode`:

```
public class TreeNode
    {
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public Machine MachineObject { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: If I do remove the inheritance to TreeViewItem I cannot programatically create my tree.

Comment: Thank you now I understand, when I create a TreeNode, I can simply set the color there, do not need to bind it.

Comment: I do not know your specifications, but the binding does work fine with the code you provided, as long as the inheritance to `TreeViewItem` is gone. Feel free to accept this answer by clicking on the gray check mark, it may be useful to other users ;)